# Minecraft CraftBukkit Server "Timing Out" on Every Startup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

Here's what's going on: I currently own and run a small CraftBukkit Server that I host on my desktop computer (see specs below) at my home and, for the most part, everything generally runs smoothly on the server.

However, a thunderstorm rolled through my area earlier today so I had to disconnect everything. I properly shutdown the server via cmd with the `stop` command and properly shutdown my computer and everything. After the storm rolled through, I connected everything back up, ran the `run.bat` file that starts the server, and then, all of a sudden I start getting random errors. Sometimes this happens so I didn't think much of it because it was the same general error that usually pops up time to time. I try connecting and it worked, I started working on the spawn and a short time later it timed out. I disconnect, tried re-connecting again and no luck. I issued the `stop` command on the console, started it back up and the same error happened again but only this time I couldn't connect at all. I ran this cycle a few more time and eventually gave up.

Here's the console log on startup:

```
[17:57:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.7.9
[17:57:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[17:57:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[17:57:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[17:57:00] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[17:57:01] [Server thread/INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks (MC: 1.7.9) (Implementing API version 1.7.9-R0.2)
[17:57:01] [Thread-8/WARN]: Could not get information about this CraftBukkit version; perhaps you are running a custom one?: IOException
[17:57:01] [Server thread/ERROR]: ebean.properties not found
[17:57:01] [Server thread/INFO]: DataSourcePool [AntiMobSpawn] autoCommit[false] transIsolation[SERIALIZABLE] min[2] max[20]
[17:57:01] [Thread-8/WARN]: Could not get latest artifact information: IOException
[17:57:01] [Server thread/INFO]: SubClassFactory parent ClassLoader [org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader]
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: Entities enhanced[0] subclassed[1]
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [GroupManager] Loading GroupManager v2.1.28 (Phoenix)
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [RandomTeleport] Loading RandomTeleport vmaven-version-number
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Loading WorldEdit v5.6.3
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [CoreProtect] Loading CoreProtect v2.0.9
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] Loading Vault v1.4.1-b436
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [ClearLag] Loading ClearLag v2.7.2
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [HolographicDisplays] Loading HolographicDisplays v1.8.7
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [AntiMobSpawn] Loading AntiMobSpawn v5.0
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldGuard] Loading WorldGuard v5.9
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Essentials] Loading Essentials v2.13.1
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [WarpPortals] Loading WarpPortals v5.6.3
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [IFS] Loading ItemFrameShops v3.0.4-BETA
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Loading EssentialsProtect v2.13.1
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Loading EssentialsSpawn v2.13.1
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsChat] Loading EssentialsChat v2.13.1
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [EssentialsAntiBuild] Loading EssentialsAntiBuild v2.13.1
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [EnjinMinecraftPlugin] Loading EnjinMinecraftPlugin v2.6.8
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] Enabling Vault v1.4.1-b436
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] [Economy] Essentials Economy found: Waiting
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] [Permission] GroupManager found: Waiting
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] [Permission] SuperPermissions loaded as backup permission system.
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] [Chat] GroupManager found: Waiting
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] Enabled Version 1.4.1-b436
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[17:57:02] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: -5525313413541735195)
[17:57:03] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 24%
[17:57:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 71%
[17:57:05] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagList.load(SourceFile:37) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagList.load(SourceFile:37) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.a(SourceFile:329) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.load(SourceFile:41) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:120) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:89) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:85) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkRegionLoader.loadChunk(ChunkRegionLoader.java:83) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage1(ChunkIOProvider.java:19) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage1(ChunkIOProvider.java:13) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.util.AsynchronousExecutor.skipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:336) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.util.AsynchronousExecutor.getSkipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:295) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOExecutor.syncChunkLoad(ChunkIOExecutor.java:16) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(ChunkProviderServer.java:116) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(ChunkProviderServer.java:98) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.g(MinecraftServer.java:317) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:282) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:182) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks]
[17:57:05] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: C:\Documents and Settings\owner\Desktop\Bukkit Server 1.7.10\.\crash-reports\crash-2014-10-13_17.57.05-server.txt
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: [Vault] Disabling Vault v1.4.1-b436
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/Overworld
[17:58:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world_the_end'/The End
[17:58:34] [Thread-4/INFO]: Stopping server
[17:58:34] [Thread-4/INFO]: Saving players
[17:58:34] [Thread-4/INFO]: Saving worlds
[17:58:34] [Thread-4/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/Overworld
[17:58:34] [Thread-4/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world_the_end'/The End
```

Note that there are a few `IOExceptions` here and there, I'm not sure if those have anything to do with the server suddenly timming out at every startup or not. The `IOExceptions` have always been there and reakky haven't caused any troubles as far as I can tell.

Here is the crash report as well:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Don't be sad. I'll do better next time, I promise!
Time: 10/13/14 5:57 PM
Description: Exception in server tick loop
java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception in server tick loop
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagList.load(SourceFile:37)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagList.load(SourceFile:37)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.a(SourceFile:329)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.load(SourceFile:41)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:120)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:89)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTCompressedStreamTools.a(SourceFile:85)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkRegionLoader.loadChunk(ChunkRegionLoader.java:83)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage1(ChunkIOProvider.java:19)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOProvider.callStage1(ChunkIOProvider.java:13)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.util.AsynchronousExecutor.skipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:336)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.util.AsynchronousExecutor.getSkipQueue(AsynchronousExecutor.java:295)
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOExecutor.syncChunkLoad(ChunkIOExecutor.java:16)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(ChunkProviderServer.java:116)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ChunkProviderServer.getChunkAt(ChunkProviderServer.java:98)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.g(MinecraftServer.java:317)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:282)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:182)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:436)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628)
A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.7.9
Operating System: Windows XP (x86) version 5.1
Java Version: 1.7.0_67, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 50659160 bytes (48 MB) / 115728384 bytes (110 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
JVM Flags: 1 total; -Xmx1024M
AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
CraftBukkit Information:
    Running: CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-10-g8688bd4-b3092jnks (MC: 1.7.9) (Implementing API version 1.7.9-R0.2) true
    Plugins: { GroupManager v2.1.28 (Phoenix) org.anjocaido.groupmanager.GroupManager [AnjoCaido, Gabriel Couto, ElgarL], RandomTeleport vmaven-version-number com.atomic.rtp.RandomTeleport [], WorldEdit v5.6.3 com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.WorldEditPlugin [], CoreProtect v2.0.9 net.coreprotect.CoreProtect [Intelli], Vault v1.4.1-b436 net.milkbowl.vault.Vault [cereal, Sleaker, mung3r], ClearLag v2.7.2 me.minebuilders.clearlag.Clearlag [bob7l], HolographicDisplays v1.8.7 com.gmail.filoghost.holograms.HolographicDisplays [], AntiMobSpawn v5.0 uk.samlex.ams.AntiMobSpawn [Sam_lex], WorldGuard v5.9 com.sk89q.worldguard.bukkit.WorldGuardPlugin [], Essentials v2.13.1 com.earth2me.essentials.Essentials [Zenexer, ementalo, Aelux, Brettflan, KimKandor, snowleo, ceulemans, Xeology, KHobbits, md_5, Iaccidentally], WarpPortals v5.6.3 com.mccraftaholics.warpportals.bukkit.PortalPlugin [], ItemFrameShops v3.0.4-BETA com.woutwoot.ItemFrameShops.Main [woutwoot], EssentialsProtect v2.13.1 com.earth2me.essentials.protect.EssentialsProtect [Zenexer, ementalo, Aelux, Brettflan, KimKandor, snowleo, ceulemans, Xeology, KHobbits], EssentialsSpawn v2.13.1 com.earth2me.essentials.spawn.EssentialsSpawn [Zenexer, ementalo, Aelux, Brettflan, KimKandor, snowleo, ceulemans, Xeology, KHobbits], EssentialsChat v2.13.1 com.earth2me.essentials.chat.EssentialsChat [Zenexer, ementalo, Aelux, Brettflan, KimKandor, snowleo, ceulemans, Xeology, KHobbits, md_5, Okamosy, Iaccidentally], EssentialsAntiBuild v2.13.1 com.earth2me.essentials.antibuild.EssentialsAntiBuild [Zenexer, ementalo, Aelux, Brettflan, KimKandor, snowleo, ceulemans, Xeology, KHobbits, Iaccidentally], EnjinMinecraftPlugin v2.6.8 com.enjin.officialplugin.EnjinMinecraftPlugin [www.Enjin.com],} Warnings: DEFAULT Threads: { WAITING Java2D Disposer: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)], TIMED_WAITING EbeanCacheWarmer: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source), java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)], RUNNABLE DestroyJavaVM: [], RUNNABLE Thread-5: [java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method), java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source), java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source), java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source), java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source), org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiOutputStream.write(AnsiOutputStream.java:82), java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source), java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source), java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.util.TerminalConsoleWriterThread.run(TerminalConsoleWriterThread.java:34), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)], RUNNABLE Server thread: [java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads(Native Method), java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Unknown Source), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftCrashReport.call(CraftCrashReport.java:28), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.CrashReportSystemDetails.a(SourceFile:74), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.CrashReport.h(CrashReport.java:45), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.CrashReport.<init>(CrashReport.java:33), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:486), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628)], WAITING Reference Handler: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503), java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)], TIMED_WAITING Keep-Alive-Timer: [java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method), sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(Unknown Source), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)], WAITING Finalizer: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source), java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)], WAITING Ebean-AntiMobSpawn.0: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503), com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.thread.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:75), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)], RUNNABLE Attach Listener: [], RUNNABLE Server console handler: [org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32._getch(Native Method), org.fusesource.jansi.internal.WindowsSupport.readByte(WindowsSupport.java:46), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.WindowsTerminal.readByte(WindowsTerminal.java:184), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.WindowsTerminal.access$000(WindowsTerminal.java:53), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.WindowsTerminal$1.read(WindowsTerminal.java:151), java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader$1.read(ConsoleReader.java:167), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:267), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:204), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:995), org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:1167), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadCommandReader.run(ThreadCommandReader.java:32)], TIMED_WAITING Server Infinisleeper: [java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method), net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadSleepForever.run(SourceFile:65)], WAITING Snooper Timer: [java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503), java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source), java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)], RUNNABLE Netty IO #0: [sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method), sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source), sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source), sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source), sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source), sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source), net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:591), net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:301), net.minecraft.util.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)], RUNNABLE Signal Dispatcher: [], TIMED_WAITING EbeanBackgroundThread: [java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method), com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread$Runner.run(BackgroundThread.java:170), java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)],} Recent tasks from -31--1{}
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
Player Count: 0 / 22; []
Is Modded: Definitely; Server brand changed to 'CraftBukkit'
Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

As you can see in the crash report, I use Windows XP (SP3) with about 3GB RAM, about 80GB HDD (yes I know, it's old and decrepit) Intel Pentium 4 processor.

I have also deleted the `run.bat` file and created an identical one. It didn't make a difference since I still got the same type of error during startup.

So does anyone know how to fix this? Is it the fact that the computer is too old or is it within java or is it just simply my internet? (I have Fiber Optic Internet with a 5Ghz Wi-Fi connection speed)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. All I did was, unfortunately, delete my cuerrent world folder and generated a new one. But I did create another folder on my desktop the contains the old world files in it

Answer (score 1):

```
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.chunkio.ChunkIOExecutor.syncChunkLoad(ChunkIOExecutor.java:16)
```

Your Minecraft server could not sync chunks properly with what's in the memory with written files.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Exception in server tick loop
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagList.load(SourceFile:37)
```

Something went wrong when loading NBT tags.

```
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.a(SourceFile:329)
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NBTTagCompound.load(SourceFile:41)
```

Was expecting a number, not a string or a decimal thing.

---

Only thing I can think of are:

- Are you using the right version of Minecraft (ie. Didn't port a 1.8 world back into 1.7)
- Did your world previously have mods (in particular, those that use [Forge Mod Loader](http://www.minecraftforge.net) (FML)?

Comment: 1) I am currently using Minecraft 1.7.10, that is the version that I am connecting to the server with. 2) No, I haven't used any mods or Forge, just strictly Bukkit Plugins. 3) What exactly are NBT tags and why didn't the chunks sync properly?

Comment: Could it be possible that if I delete the world folder and create a new one it would fix the problem?

Comment: If you have run your server previously on a 1.8 server, you have no hope of converting it backwards. If all else fails - Create a new world (delete the `world`, `world_nether` and `world_the_end` folders while the server is stopped, then restart the server).